# Visual Studio 2017: .rptproj vs .sqlproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2017

I have inherited a C# code base that started life in VS2013.  We are now moving to VS2017 (from VS2015).  The solution contains a number of *.rptproj* projects used to manage the database schemas.  After installing [MS Report Projects for VS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio) I can now open the *.rptproj* projects in VS.  However, if I create a new database project the file suffix is *.sqlproj*. As far as I can see these projects are the same, as they appear in the IDE at least, so I'm a little confused as to what the difference is?  Is it purely a name change for some reason is is there more significance to this? I'm definitely missing something here.

Comment: SSDT and SSDT-BI are different products. Why would you use reporting project manage db schema while SSDT is better at that? SSDT is very advanced in managing database as project, not only schema. For RS project, I guess you can only manage a few scripts.

Answer (score 8):

.sqlproj files are for  writing and deploying sql database objects (tables, views, stored procedures etc)

.rptproj files are for writing reporting services reports

They are different and both awesome :)

Comment: just to clarify when i said reporting services was awesome, i didn't mean it - hope no one minds